# 2 of my sliders do not show on page load in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

The page at: http://kangalisting.com/exper/ax2.html has 3 sliders beside each other down above the YouTube videos slider. When the page loads, the 2 sliders on the right that have images in them, randomly show the images on page load, sometimes you need to click a slider button to activate the image. Any thoughts? It is possible it is happening on other OS'es than win8.

Comment: Show some code! You mean it's only working in Win 8? In which browser?

Comment: It's hard to say since you aren't showing code but I noticed on those two sliders you have the same image multiple times as opposed to the one that works has different images... is this causing issues with your javasript mabye?